# How to set a specific language in a specific color in Notepad++ or Sublime Text

Tags: notepad++, sublimetext3

How do I set a specific language, like Japanese Chinese Russian, in a specific color in Notepad++ or Sublime Text 3?

```
string 去空格(string line) {
  for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++) {
    if (line[i]!=' ' && line[i]!='\t')
      return line.substr(i, line.length()-i);
  }
  return line;
}
```

In comments, we use our local language instead of English. We may use local language as a variable, function or class. I want of them in color.

Comment: I'm afraid that can't be done. How could you know the language where a word comes from?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages. We'd like to see where you researched this, why it didn't help, and what you tried to solve this. Color schemes break code into various components, including comments, functions/methods, classes, parameters, keywords, etc., allowing colorizing and styling. This is covered in many places for Sublime.